# Vector of queues of different types

Tags: c++, templates

I have a type, let's call it T. It can be of different types, and I do not know them in advance:
int, double, bitmap pointer...
Now, I have a class, let's call it C. It should maintain a vector of queues of T.
Each queue has its unique type of elements, but it is possible that C has a vector (or whatever other way of maintaining multiple queues) with few queues of different types:

queue, queue, ...

So my question is: is there a way to pass variable number types to a class?
Example: I need to get <int, double, double, int> and in a constructor, to create corresponding queues, plus I will need a function to get/put data to a particular queue (say, queue No 3 in a list).

I know about variadic templates, but can not figure how to use it: it looks like I have to do it recursively, and I am not that advanced...

I can do it using "any", but then get/put will have "any" as well, and I do not know how to do a type check, so the user doesn't send a double instead of string, or something like that.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Could a `union` work? Could a vector of an abstract base class, with subclasses acting as specific containers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually not that complicated. You don't even need recursion. Just [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple)

```
#include <tuple>
#include <queue>

template <class... Args>
struct C
{
    std::tuple<std::queue<Args>...> queues_;

    template <std::size_t I>
    auto& queue_at()
    {
        return std::get<I>(queues_);
    }
};

auto test()
{
    C<int, double, bool> c;

    std::queue<int>& q1 = c.queue_at<0>();
    std::queue<double>& q2 = c.queue_at<1>();
}
```

Comment: This is very impressive.
So get<I>(queues_) returns the queue number I, correct?
And queues_ are created in std::tuple<std::queue<Args>...> queues_; and q[i] has type, corresponding to Args[i] (by [i] I mean "number i in a list")?

Comment: Could you also clarify:

Can I create queues using "new" and store pointers (what would be the syntax)?

Also, I need to pass to the class a function pointer with the same arguments and store it as a class member: again, what a syntax should be?

The reason for this question: we write class C, while the user provides function that takes data from queues and does some user-defined operations.

Thank you

Comment: @SteveBrown as I've shown in the example, `c.queue_at<0>()` has type `std::queue<int>` and so on. `std::tuple` stores all queues. You can create using `new`,  but in C++ you should never use explicit `new` (except in low level library code). I don't know why you would want that. As for the function pointer question I don't understand you should probably ask a new question. I would however try and experiment first before asking a question.

Comment: In any case, thank you. I will try it, at least I know the direction now :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use variadic template with recursive inheritance:

```cpp
#include <queue>
#include <string>

template <typename First, typename... Rest>
struct Base : Base<First>,  Base<Rest...> {
};

template <typename First>
struct Base<First> {
    std::queue<First> q;
};


int main (){
    auto f = Base<int, std::string>{};

    static_cast<Base<int>>(f).q.emplace(32);
    static_cast<Base<std::string>>(f).q.emplace("sdf");
   
    // not allowed
    // static_cast<Base<float>>(f).q.emplace(1231.2);
}
```

Comment: What if I have <int, double, int>? and regardless same "int" type, data are different? How do I distinguish static_cast<Base<int>>(f).q.emplace(32); of first "int" and third one?

Comment: Then there will be a compilation error `Base<int> is an ambiguous base of`. It really depends on your needs. Sorry I missed that requirement from your question. In that case the `tuple` approach is a superior solution